# playaudio() function does not work in Octave

Tags: matlab, audio, octave

I need to play an wav file on Octave. When I call playaudio("sample","wav") function. I get this error :

error: playaudio does not support given extension

error: called from:

error:   /usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/audio/playaudio.m at line 70, column 7

How could I solve this problem? How can I make playaudio support wav. format.

Comment: Maybe you find [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130942/reading-and-playing-sound-in-octave-on-fedora12) to be helpful. It appears that you have to use [`wavread`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Audio-Processing.html#XREFwavread) first.

Answer (score 1):

The source code for the `playaudio` function is very straightforward:

```
if (any (strcmp (ext, {"lin", "raw"})))
  [status, out] = system (sprintf ('cat "%s" > /dev/dsp', name));
  if (status != 0)
    system (sprintf ('paplay --raw "%s"', name));
  endif
elseif (any (strcmp (ext, {"mu", "au" "snd", "ul"})))
  [status, out] = system (sprintf ('cat "%s" > /dev/audio', name));
  if (status != 0)
    system (sprintf ('paplay "%s"', name));
  endif
else
  error ("playaudio: unsupported extension '%s'", ext);
endif
```

As you can see, it's simply doing a system call with the `paplay` utility available in all Linux systems using the [PulseAudio](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/) sound server. If you have the permission to edit the `playaudio.m` file yourself, just add the "wav" extension to the list as in:

```
elseif (any (strcmp (ext, {"mu", "au" "snd", "ul", "wav"})))
```

It should work out of the box.

I'll submit this patch to the GNU Octave bug tracking system. Thanks for reporting the issue.

---

Patch submitted: https://savannah.gnu.org/patch/index.php?8441

Comment: @jason, if you don't have permission to edit the file in place, copy it to your project directory, do the modification and remove it in the future when the fix is available. Alternatively, you can directly use the `system` call yourself.